# Initializing a functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have created a function that creates some ammount of random cards, but my Init function returns undefined when I call it like init(1). Why doesn't it work? It should be like:
1. I'm calling a function for example init(1)
2. Init creates and shuffles cards and appends them to the body

```js
// INIT 
{
  function init(difficulty) {
    switch (difficulty)  {
      case 1:
          createCards(4);
          break;
      case 2:
          createCards(12);
          break;
      case 0:
          createCards(24);
    }
  }
//FLIP CARD
function createCards(ammount) {
  const gameCards = []
  for (let i = 0; i < ammount; i++) {
    const gameCard = document.createElement("div");
    gameCard.className = "card  card--click";
    const gameCardFront = document.createElement("div");
    const gameCardBack = document.createElement("div"); 
    gameCard.appendChild(gameCardFront);
    gameCard.appendChild(gameCardBack);
    gameCardFront.className = "card__front  card--reversed";
    gameCardBack.className = "card__back";
    const img = new Image();
    function randImg() {
      const uniqueSrc = {}
      const imgArray = ["ball", "car", "fork", "spoon", "sun"];
      const gameArray = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < ammount * 2 + 1; i++) {
        const randomSrc = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imgArray.length));
        if (!uniqueSrc[randomSrc]) {
          uniqueSrc[randomSrc] = randomSrc;
          img.src = "img/" + imgArray[randomSrc] + ".png";
          img.alt = imgArray[randomSrc];
          gameArray.push(img);
        } else {
            i--;
        }
      }
      return gameArray;
    }
    randImg();
    gameCardBack.appendChild(img);
    gameCards.push(gameCard)
  }
    return gameCards;
  }
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card.card--click");
      //FETCHING ALL CARDS
   for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    const card = cards[i];
      //ADDING FLIP EFFECT TO EACH CARD
    flipCard(card);
  };
      //FLIP EFFECT FUNCTION
  function flipCard(card) {
    card.addEventListener("click", function() {
      const list = this.classList;
      list.contains("card--flip") === true ? list.remove("card--flip") : list.add("card--flip");
    });
  };
  function randomizer(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        const tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = tmp;
    }
    return array;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the surrounding brackets

Comment: i think the main problem is that youre not doing anything with the data returned by createCards(4)

Comment: @Brian wrong they are totally fine...  ( but unneccessary)

Comment: @AlexanderR. functions are in a function scope, brackets create a block scope. So your statement is wrong.

Comment: @Jonasw You're right. Ran beautify on the code, I assumed the function init was surrounded by brackets.

Comment: @Jonasw you are right. I just assumed JS's brackets works like brackets in C =))

Answer (score 1):

1) The thing is that youre not appending your cards to body. So you may want to return the cards in the init function:

```
function init(difficulty) {
switch (difficulty)  {
  case 1:
      return createCards(4);
      break;
  case 2:
      return createCards(12);
      break;
  case 0:
      return createCards(24);
   }
 }
```

Then you can append the Array returned by init to body:

```
init(0).forEach(function(card){
  document.body.appendChild(card);
});
```

2)Also this:

```
randImg();
```

doesnt make sense as randImg returns an array, you may wanna catch it:

```
arr=randImg();
```

3) Also the randImg will not work, you need to put the

```
const img=new Image();
```

into the loop.

4) And

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card.card--click");
```

Will be an empty collection unless you run the snippet above before...

Comment: thanks that's what I was looking for but can you give me some details how to run init function like SPA (I have options easy medium hard and I want cards after clicking on one of these) This curly brace was for a block of code instead of writting IIFE

Comment: @Miqez have a look at codeblock two.It already cntains the code to execute init with a certain difficulty. and yes i needed a moment to understand your use of a block, however i wouldnt recomend to use it as its quite new in js...